# Assign multiple rows to one index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in Pandas which looks like this:

```
           Activity Name Activity Start Activity End
0                  Phone          04:00        08:00
1                  Lunch          08:00        08:30
2                 Coffee          08:30        08:45
3                  Phone          08:45        10:30
4         WrittenSupport          10:30        12:30
5                  Phone          04:00        08:00
6                  Lunch          08:00        08:30
7                 Coffee          08:30        08:45
8                  Phone          08:45        09:00
9                  Phone          06:00        09:00
```

The data inside my DataFrame describes different activities assigned to an agent during the shift. The issue is that another DataFrame with agents has only 57 names while there are usually 4-5 activities assigned to a person. When I merge my DataFrames I end up with 57 agents and 265 activities that obviously do not match designated people.

What can be helpful: each person works 8 hours.

How do I transform it to look like this:

```
           Activity Name Activity Start Activity End
0                  Phone          04:00        08:00
                   Lunch          08:00        08:30
                  Coffee          08:30        08:45
                   Phone          08:45        10:30
          WrittenSupport          10:30        12:30
1                  Phone          04:00        08:00
                   Lunch          08:00        08:30
                  Coffee          08:30        08:45
                   Phone          08:45        09:00
                   Phone          06:00        09:00
```

Comment: Are the numbers in your example the IDs for the agents?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock No, those are row indices. But those could as well be agent names. The idea is to have one agent and 4-5 activities clearly assigned to them in the DataFrame.

Comment: Is there additional that shows the date of the shift? It is problematic to differentiate between two shifts that happened on different days, but on the same hour

Comment: @OhadChaet The whole DataFrame covers only one day.

Answer (score 4):

If you have seperate rows for your agents and activities you could create a multi-index like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# This is the dataframe data with activities you got from a single agent
agent_1 = [['Phone', 'Phone', 'Coffee', 'Lunch', 'Phone', 'Phone', 'Lunch', 'Lunch'],
           ['04:00', '08:30', '10:30', '04:00', '10:30', '04:00', '08:30', '10:30']]

# This is the dataframe data from a second agent
agent_2 = [['Phone', 'Pooping', 'Coffee', 'Lunch', 'Phone', 'Meeting', 'Lunch', 'Lunch'],
           ['08:45', '08:50', '10:30', '04:00', '10:30', '04:00', '08:30', '10:30']]

# We create the dataframe for agent 1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(agent_1).T
df1.columns = ['activity', 'time']


# We create the dataframe for agent 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(agent_2).T
df2.columns = ['activity', 'time']

# Now we have to dataframes we can't really put together
print(df1)
print("----")
print(df2)
print("----")

# So we should give each dataframe a column with its agent.
df1['agent'] = "Agent_1"
df2['agent'] = "Agent_2"

# Now each dataframe has data on its agent
print(df1)
print("----")
print(df2)
print("----")

# Let's combine them
overview = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(overview)
print("----")

# To make it even better, we could make a multi-index so we can index both agents AND activities
overview.set_index(['agent', 'activity'], inplace=True)
print(overview)
```

Output:

```
  activity   time
0    Phone  04:00
1    Phone  08:30
2   Coffee  10:30
3    Lunch  04:00
4    Phone  10:30
5    Phone  04:00
6    Lunch  08:30
7    Lunch  10:30
----
  activity   time
0    Phone  08:45
1  Pooping  08:50
2   Coffee  10:30
3    Lunch  04:00
4    Phone  10:30
5  Meeting  04:00
6    Lunch  08:30
7    Lunch  10:30
----
  activity   time    agent
0    Phone  04:00  Agent_1
1    Phone  08:30  Agent_1
2   Coffee  10:30  Agent_1
3    Lunch  04:00  Agent_1
4    Phone  10:30  Agent_1
5    Phone  04:00  Agent_1
6    Lunch  08:30  Agent_1
7    Lunch  10:30  Agent_1
----
  activity   time    agent
0    Phone  08:45  Agent_2
1  Pooping  08:50  Agent_2
2   Coffee  10:30  Agent_2
3    Lunch  04:00  Agent_2
4    Phone  10:30  Agent_2
5  Meeting  04:00  Agent_2
6    Lunch  08:30  Agent_2
7    Lunch  10:30  Agent_2
----
  activity   time    agent
0    Phone  04:00  Agent_1
1    Phone  08:30  Agent_1
2   Coffee  10:30  Agent_1
3    Lunch  04:00  Agent_1
4    Phone  10:30  Agent_1
5    Phone  04:00  Agent_1
6    Lunch  08:30  Agent_1
7    Lunch  10:30  Agent_1
0    Phone  08:45  Agent_2
1  Pooping  08:50  Agent_2
2   Coffee  10:30  Agent_2
3    Lunch  04:00  Agent_2
4    Phone  10:30  Agent_2
5  Meeting  04:00  Agent_2
6    Lunch  08:30  Agent_2
7    Lunch  10:30  Agent_2
----
                   time
agent   activity       
Agent_1 Phone     04:00
        Phone     08:30
        Coffee    10:30
        Lunch     04:00
        Phone     10:30
        Phone     04:00
        Lunch     08:30
        Lunch     10:30
Agent_2 Phone     08:45
        Pooping   08:50
        Coffee    10:30
        Lunch     04:00
        Phone     10:30
        Meeting   04:00
        Lunch     08:30
        Lunch     10:30
```

Comment: This has to happen automatically. I parse an HTML page and get the list of agents, activity names and activity timespans.

Comment: @anyplane I'm not sure what the problem is then. Could you explain how this solution is different from your goal?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your solution, but I just get the name of each agent and a lot of different activities. The only two consistent things that can help us are: each agent works 8 hours, the activity start time increments and then resets(e.g. 04:00, 06:00, 08:00, 12:00, 04:00). The timeframe between 12:00 and 04:00 is when the shift goes to the next agent.

Comment: I edited the solution. I think this is clearer on how it could work.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the folowing data(added some for verification):

```
print(df)
     Activity Name Activity Start Activity End
0            Phone       04:00:00     08:00:00
1            Lunch       08:00:00     08:30:00
2           Coffee       08:30:00     08:45:00
3            Phone       08:45:00     10:30:00
4   WrittenSupport       10:30:00     12:30:00
5            Phone       04:00:00     08:00:00
6            Lunch       08:00:00     08:30:00
7           Coffee       08:30:00     08:45:00
8            Phone       08:45:00     09:00:00
9            Phone       06:00:00     09:00:00
10  Someother Name       10:30:00     12:30:00
11           Phone       04:00:00     08:00:00
12           Lunch       08:00:00     08:30:00
13          Coffee       08:30:00     08:45:00
14           Phone       08:45:00     09:00:00
15           Phone       06:00:00     09:00:00
```

Using the below:

```
df['index_col']=df[~df.duplicated('Activity Name',keep=False)].expanding().count().iloc[:,1]
df_new=df.set_index(df.index_col.ffill().fillna(0)).rename_axis(None).drop('index_col',1)
print(df_new)

      Activity Name Activity Start Activity End
0.0           Phone       04:00:00     08:00:00
0.0           Lunch       08:00:00     08:30:00
0.0          Coffee       08:30:00     08:45:00
0.0           Phone       08:45:00     10:30:00
1.0  WrittenSupport       10:30:00     12:30:00
1.0           Phone       04:00:00     08:00:00
1.0           Lunch       08:00:00     08:30:00
1.0          Coffee       08:30:00     08:45:00
1.0           Phone       08:45:00     09:00:00
1.0           Phone       06:00:00     09:00:00
2.0  Someother Name       10:30:00     12:30:00
2.0           Phone       04:00:00     08:00:00
2.0           Lunch       08:00:00     08:30:00
2.0          Coffee       08:30:00     08:45:00
2.0           Phone       08:45:00     09:00:00
2.0           Phone       06:00:00     09:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to do it by creating a list of the different indexes, like this:

```
times = [int(x[1][:2]) for x in your_array]
previous = 0
index=[1]
next_agent= 2
for time in times:
    if time >= previous:
        index.append(‘´)
    else:
        index.append(next_agent)
        next_agent+=1
    previous = time
```

then to set the df:

```
df= DataFrame(your_array, index=index, columns=column)
```